# mongodb checking an array of strings in another array and adding status field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have a Job collection like below

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5b6abaaf9bcdb5d4ae6491d2"),
"jobID" : "1",
"userID":"5",
"jobstatus" : "Active",
"shortListedUsers" : [ 
    "1", 
    "2"
],
"appliedUsers" : [ 
    "1", 
    "2", 
    "3",
    "4"
]
```

and User collection like below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b59610208253701e11d7a02"),
    "userID" : "1",
    "user_Name" : "prasanth"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b59611808253701e11d7a14"),
    "userID" : "2",
    "user_Name" : "harish"  
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b596e6b08253701e11d896c"),
    "userID" : "3",
    "user_Name" : "dinesh"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b596e6b08253701e11d8962"),
    "userID" : "4",
    "user_Name" : "ravi"
}
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b596e6b08253701e11d896c"),
        "userID" : "5",
        "user_Name" : "kohli"
        "friendlist":["1"]
    }
```

i want output like this

Output:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b59610208253701e11d7a02"),
        "userID" : "1",
        "user_Name" : "prasanth",
        "status":"shortlisted",
        "firendstatus":"friend"
    }

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b59611808253701e11d7a14"),
        "userID" : "2",
        "user_Name" : "harish",
        "status":"shortlisted",
        "firendstatus":"requestsent"


    }

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b596e6b08253701e11d896c"),
        "userID" : "3",
        "user_Name" : "dinesh"
        "status":"not shortlisted"
         "firendstatus":"request received"

    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b596e6b08253701e11d896c"),
        "userID" : "4",
        "user_Name" : "ravi"
        "status":"not shortlisted"
          "firendstatus":"not friend"

    }
```

FriendRequest collection:

```
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b596e6b08253701e11d896c"),
            "formuserID" : "5",
            "touserID" : "2"
        }
         {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b596e6b08253701e11d896c"),
            "formuserID" : "3",
            "touserID" : "5"
        }
```

I will pass  jobid and userid as input.I want firendstatus along with status.
firendstatus  string update conditions:

friend:when applied userid in appliedUsers arraylist from Job collection present in friendlist array of userID who was posted the job then update string as(firendstatus  :friend) in output

requestsent:when job posted user sends a friend request to another user then
(firendstatus  :requestsent) in output.
    EX:userid 5 sends friend request to userid 2.(FriendRequest collection)
request received::when job posted user receives a friend request from another user then (firendstatus  :request received) in output.

not friend: when shortlisted user is not in friendlist of job posted user
           when shortlisted user does not send friend request to job posted user
          when shortlisted user does receive friend request from job posted user

please help me.Thank you

i am using the below query but its not giving requestsent and request received.I didn't understand how to do.

```
db.Shortlistjobs.aggregate([
{"$match":{"jobID":"job1"}},
{"$lookup":{
 "from":"User",
 "let":{"appliedUsers":"$appliedUsers", "shortListedUser":"$shortListedUser"},
 "pipeline":[
   {"$match":{"$expr":{"$in":["$userID","$$appliedUsers"]}}},
   {"$addFields":{
      "status":{"$cond":[{"$in":["$userID","$$shortListedUser"]},"shortlisted","not shortlisted"]}
    }},
{"$addFields":{
     "friend_status":{"$cond":[{"$in":["$userID",["1","2","3","4"]]},"friend","not friend"]}
   }},

 ],
 "as":"users"
}},


{"$unwind":"$users"},
{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$users"}}

])
```

Comment: @Veeram help me out this

Comment: @Veeram pls help

Answer (score 1):

You can use below pipeline in 3.6.

[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with pipeline to join the job collection to user collection on applied users.

[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) to compare the shortlisted users against each user id in the user collection and add a new field to the user document.

[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to promote all the users to the top level.

```
db.Job.aggregate([
{"$match":{"jobID":"1"}},
{"$lookup":{
  "from":"User",
  "let":{"appliedUsers":"$appliedUsers", "shortListedUsers":"$shortListedUsers"},
  "pipeline":[
    {"$match":{"$expr":{"$in":["$userID","$$appliedUsers"]}}},
    {"$addFields":{
      "status":{"$cond":[{"$in":["$userID","$$shortListedUsers"]},"shortlisted","not shortlisted"]}
    }}
  ],
  "as":"users"
}},
{"$unwind":"$users"},
{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$users"}}
])
```

Comment: do you want to exclude the job documents when appliedUsers is not there ?

Comment: Change your match to `{"$match":{"jobID":"1", "appliedUsers":{"$exists":true}}}`

Comment: Thanks!.I will take a look shortly.

Comment: Yw. Do you mind creating separate question with all the details ? It appears you are asking a entirely new function. If possible I will answer the new question.

Comment: sure i will post a new one

Answer (score 0):

Running join query is not a recommended way for no-sql database and your desire output needs to join. so better to use embedded document like below:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5b6abaaf9bcdb5d4ae6491d2"),
"jobID" : "1",
"jobstatus" : "Active",
"shortListedUsers" : [ 
     {
         "userID" : "3",
        "user_Name" : "dinesh"
     },{
         "userID" : "2",
        "user_Name" : "Sumit"
     }
],
"appliedUsers" : [ 
    "1", 
    "2", 
    "3"
]
}
```

The above way will make your search much simpilar and faster.

Comment: @nithin Querying like this is not a good way. I will suggest you go with the embedded document.

Comment: please dont give down votes.if this is possible help me or if question only wrong tell me.Thank you

Comment: @nithin I didn't give you down vote. Even i gives the response after understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Please try below query it is properly tested and working

```
db.job.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
   {
        $match:{
            "jobID" : "1"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$appliedUsers",
            includeArrayIndex : "arrayIndex", // optional
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false // optional
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $project: {
          "shortListedUsers":1,
          "appliedUsers":1,
           "ifMatched" : {
                $in: [ "$appliedUsers", "$shortListedUsers" ]
              }
        }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from" : "users",
            "localField" : "appliedUsers",
            "foreignField" : "userID",
            "as" : "allData"
        }
    },

    // Stage 4
    {
        $project: {
       "_id":1,
       "userID":{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$allData.userID", 0 ] },
       user_Name: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$allData.user_Name", 0 ] },
       status:{ $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$ifMatched", true ] }, then: 
       "shortlisted", else: "not shortlisted" }}
       }
    },
],
```

);

Comment: i am getting the below output.I am not getting the user douctments

Comment: /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6abaaf9bcdb5d4ae6491d2"),
    "status" : "shortlisted"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6abaaf9bcdb5d4ae6491d2"),
    "status" : "shortlisted"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6abaaf9bcdb5d4ae6491d2"),
    "status" : "not shortlisted"
}

Comment: where i need to pass the jobID

Comment: I have created query based on the required output

Comment: Please check the modified query once again

Comment: You have to apply only match condition in first step